# Is Cassandra comparable to HBase?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hbase, apache-spark-sql

HBase is known for being a key-value store and random reads with .get and .put functions based on the key. Is Cassandra a better choice for suiting a requirement of key-value store? Can it support random reads based on key? If so, in which conditions should I choose Cassandra over HBase in a Spark Streaming application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cassandra a better choice for suiting a requirement of key-value
>   store?

Yes its one of the good choice.

- Cassandra has decentralized architecture. Any node can perform any operation. It provides AP(Availability,Partition-Tolerance) from CAP theorem.
- Eventually consistent

> Can it support random reads based on key?

Yes.

> If so, in which conditions should I choose Cassandra over HBase in a
>   Spark Streaming application?

Both HBASE and CASSANDRA can be used for streaming applications. The natural choice for CASSANDRA is its high availability..

> Question in title : ***Is Cassandra comparable to HBase?***

see below for more details...

---

[image]

#### [CAP_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)

- Consistency (all nodes see the same data at the same time)
- Availability (a guarantee that every request receives a response about whether it was successful or failed)
- Partition tolerance (the system continues to operate despite arbitrary message loss or failure of part of the system)

> **Conclusion** :  CASSANDRA supports AP, if you are looking for that you can go ahead with CASSANDRA
>
> Note : As per CAP  theorem, a distributed system CANT satisfy all
>   three of these guarantees at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  It's helpful! Which api/function call can I use in Cassandra for storing key Value and lookup? Esp for Spark 2

Comment: datastax [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md) would be useful